# Sphinx fail on critical (e.g. unexpected section title)

Tags: python-3.x, python-sphinx

We have an automated build (from Python) of our docs using Sphinx.
During the build it encountered a "Critical: unexpected section title".
And indeed we had some malformed docs.

And yet, Sphinx went on and finished outputting docs without stopping and didn't report a problem at the end. I added a check of the status code from the Sphinx object after build, and it's zero.

How can I get it to stop and/or report a failure at the end, when it encountered this error?

Comment: See https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-build.html#cmdoption-sphinx-build-W

Comment: Thanks. But: Is a message marked ‘critical’ a warning? It seems unlikely. In any case I don’t want to stop on every warning

Comment: What if you use `--keep-going` in addition to `-W`? https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-build.html#cmdoption-sphinx-build-keep-going